# python3, converting integer to bytes: which are the alternatives to using to_bytes() for small integers?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a more efficient method to convert an integer, in the range 0..255 (in C uint8), to one byte?

```
x = 100
x.to_bytes(1, "big")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More efficient method for a single integer? Probably not.

Here's a comparison of the common ones:

```
python -m timeit -s "import struct" "struct.pack('<B', 100)"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 101 nsec per loop
python -m timeit "(100).to_bytes(1)"                     
5000000 loops, best of 5: 81.1 nsec per loop
python -m timeit "bytes([100])"     
2000000 loops, best of 5: 199 nsec per loop
```

If you're talking about multiple, `bytes([integers])` will probably be the most efficient.

For some premature optimization you can cache the function, which will net you a few nanoseconds:

```
python -m timeit -s "tb = int.to_bytes" "tb(100,1)" 
5000000 loops, best of 5: 78.6 nsec per loop
```

And if you want the most efficient possible, it would probably be using a tuple:

```
python -m timeit -s "b=tuple(map(int.to_bytes, range(256)))" "b[100]"
10000000 loops, best of 5: 20.9 nsec per loop
```

But personally I find it disgusting.

Comment: @KellyBundy Which Python version are you running? Try latest.

Comment: Ah, I see 3.11 got defaults. What times do you get without providing the explicit 1 in the other snippets?

Comment: @KellyBundy about the same, it doesn't make much difference. Besides, the `-s` is setup, that's not the area being tested for speed.

Comment: Well, you're already talking about differences as small as 2.5 nsec. Does omitting the 1 make an even smaller difference?

Comment: @kelly nah, does about the same. Pegs it at 3-5 nsec faster. I made it clear that it's premature optimization, but function caching is a very common approach. Wanted to give an example of what I wouldn't do unless I have to. Removal of the parameter and relying on the default may be a good idea though just for clarity.